# Flex: Image is crossing 2 divs instead of appearing beneath just 1

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to work with flexbox, so I am kinda new to it. Anyways, I am trying to
make 3 divs next to each other and I want all of the images on one div and text in the other.

I am trying it now with 2 divs. Currently I got the image crossing the 2 divs instead of just one.
What did I do wrong ? Do I need to work with margins ?

https://plnkr.co/edit/sqpAWK1h6dECDyM1SaAl?p=preview

```
<style>
  #parent {
    display: flex;
  }

  #narrow {
    width: 20%;
    background: lightblue;
    /* Just so it's visible */
  }

  #wide {
    width: 20%;
    /* Grow to rest of container */
    background: lightgreen;
    /* Just so it's visible */
  }
</style>


<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">images) <img class="imageright" src="https://placehold.it/300x200" /></div>
  <div id="narrow">text (200px)
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   #wide {
>     width: 20%;
>     /* Grow to rest of container */
>     background: lightgreen;
>     /* Just so it's visible */
>   }
> ```

You say "Grow to rest of container", but you've done nothing to make that happen.

The default value of `flex-grow` is `0`, so it *won't* grow. Set that to `1` if you want the content to expand.

Comment: Aah yes, I see now. But I don't want it always to cover my whole page. At least width-wise. So I still have to work with margins ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question, I tried to get an answer. I added one css property to your img tag.

```
<style>
  #parent {
    display: flex-grow;
  }

  #narrow {
    width: 20%;
    background: lightblue;
    /* Just so it's visible */
  }

  #wide {
    width: 20%;
    /* Grow to rest of container */
    background: lightgreen;
    /* Just so it's visible */
  }

  .imageright{
     width:100%; 
  }
  }
</style>


<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">images) <img class="imageright" src="https://placehold.it/300x200" /></div>
  <div id="narrow">text (200px)
  </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me if this is what you expected.

Comment: Uhhm, It is now below each other. I want the 2 divs next to each other, but as I already saw in other comments, I have to put a 1 in the flex-grow